# Fabric crashlytics not display crash in some devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, google-fabric

In my iOS app one crash are generate at run time and display in fabric crashlytics.

This kind of issue raise in fabric console.

**Devices 1** is **display** crash in Crashlytics.
**Devices 2** is **not display** crash in Crashlytics.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: check if there any missing DYSM

Comment: Yes there is display missing dSYMs.

but I add dSYMs.zip  file.

Answer (score 0):

You should add that missing dysm

[link for ducmentation to add DYSM](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/_sources/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.txt)

Comment: I added .zip file

Comment: did you added it for your latest version

Comment: then check you DYSM again it should not contain any missing DYSM

Answer (score 0):

On project target -> Build Settings -> Build Options -> Debug Information Format, set it "DWARF with dSYM File". It is not for display crashes that you can not see now. But after this configuration, you can see all crashes.